# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
E:\WORK\python\Flask>virtualenv enb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\run\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..seed.wheels.periodic_update import manual_upgrade
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .acquire import get_wheel, pip_wheel_env_run
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\acquire.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .bundle import from_bundle
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\bundle.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .periodic_update import periodic_update
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv\seed\wheels\periodic_update.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

E:\WORK\python\Flask>
```

how can I solve this ?